# Does Haskell provide an idiom for pattern matching against many possible data constructors?

Tags: haskell, lambda, pattern-matching

Working on a Haskell project, I'm dealing with the `Event` data type from the [FSNotify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fsnotify-0.2.1/docs/System-FSNotify.html) package. The constructors for `Event` are all:

```
Added FilePath UTCTime
Modified FilePath UTCTime
Removed FilePath UTCTime
```

In my code, I'm only interested in extracting the `FilePath` from the `Event` and doing the same action regardless of the type constructor; because of this, I'm tempted to make a lambda.

Unfortunately, the code suffers reduced readability when I drop a `case` expression into the lambda to pattern match against all three cases; is there some built-in idiom to extract just the `FilePath` in one expression without having to manually pattern match, given the relative homogeneity of the type constructors?

I've tried passing this expression as an anonymous function in a call to the `watchDir` action:

```
 wm <- startManager
 sw <- watchDir wm "." (\_ -> True) (\(_ f t) -> putStrLn f)
```

But, predictably, the don't-care value in the lambda's pattern match causes a parse error.

Comment: Why don't you use `eventTime` / `eventPath` accessor function that this module provides?

Comment: That's actually a great solution, and solves my issue. I'd overlooked it while reading the docs. I'm going to leave the question open for a little while longer because I'm interested to see if there's a general-purpose equivalent of this.

Comment: I think there's an argument to be made that there should only be one constructor, `Event FilePath UTCTime EventType`, with `data EventType = Added | Modified | Removed`.

Comment: @chepner, I don't know anything about this library, but there could be performance reasons for this choice.

Comment: May I ask you why you accepted that answer? Did you decide to modify the library to suit your needs? If your question is to solve that problem in the general setting, then I suggest you reword it to clarify this. It doesn't make sense to have the question asking A, and an accepted answer that answers B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way would be to actually reflect the homogenity of the alternatives in the type declaration, instead of just observing it:

```
data Action = Added | Modified | Removed

data Event = FileEvent Action FilePath UTCTime | OtherEvent ...

f :: Event -> FilePath
f (FileEvent _ path _) = path
```

In general, Haskell has no way to know that all your constructor alternatives have the same number of arguments and the same type, so no, you can't abstract over the choice of alternative.

Comment: The file event isn't just one of many events; it's a single sum type that could be wrapped with `newtype MyEvent = Event (Action, FilePath, UTCTime)` for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, if there's only file events a newtype is better.

Answer (score 4):

Arguably, this ADT would have better been implemented as

```
data Event = Event {
     eventAction :: EventAction
   , eventPath :: FilePath
   , eventTime :: UTCTime
   }
data EventAction = Addition | Modification | Removal
```

But those record accessors are actually just ordinary functions:

```
eventTime :: Event -> UTCTime
eventPath :: Event -> FilePath
```

...which of course you could have easily written yourself. But in fact the FSNotify package *provides* these precise functions, so in your case, the problem is solved.

...Or is it?

Actually, a record accessor is a bit more powerful than a getter function: it also allows you to *modify* entries, like

```
delayEvent :: Event -> Event
delayEvent ev = ev{eventTime = addUTCTime 60 $ eventTime ev}
```

You can't easily get that functionality if the type is not actually a record type.

*Or can you?*

Records as such have never really worked quite satisfyingly in Haskell: they are ad-hoc syntax that's not very consistent with the rest of the language, and they have scoping issues. In the last years there has been a movement away from these record accessors toward something much more fancy: [lenses](http://lens.github.io/tutorial.html).

Actually, in newer libraries you would even more likely find the ADT thus:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data Event = Event {
    _eventAction :: EventAction
  , _eventPath :: FilePath
  , _eventTime :: UTCTime
  }
makeLenses ''Event
```

In case you haven't come across lenses yet, these are some examples of what they allow you to do:

```
delayEvent :: Event -> Event
delayEvent = eventTime %~ addUTCTime 60

syncEventTo :: Event -> Event -> Event
syncEventTo tref = eventTime .~ tref^.eventTime
```

Now, unlike record accessors, lenses can be implemented 100% within Haskell without any need to special syntax from the compiler:

```
data Event = Added    FilePath UTCTime
           | Modified FilePath UTCTime
           | Removed  FilePath UTCTime
           deriving (Eq, Show)

eventTime :: Lens' Event UTCTime
eventTime = lens get_t set_t
 where get_t (Added    _ t) = t
       get_t (Modified _ t) = t
       get_t (Removed  _ t) = t
       set_t (Added    p _) t = Added p t
       set_t (Modified p _) t = Modified p t
       set_t (Removed  p _) t = Removed p t
```